# Google fonts and cross-browser Unicode

Tags: css, unicode, fonts, cross-browser, embedding

I'm using a google font (`Source Sans Pro`) in one of my projects. I have a class where on hover `::after` I show an arrow. The problem is except from Safari, Chrome and Firefox both showing a different symbol. I mean it is arrow but the default google font is not used in the two browsers (Chrome and Firefox) to render the Unicode `(2192)`.

See the image below to understand the issue. Is there a way to make them look the same across browsers as it is appearing in Safari?

[image]

Comment: technical nit: Source Sans is Adobe, not Google. The two collaborate on these fonts, but Adobe manages the release, and they release it as "Source". Google in turn releases their own branded copy as "Noto" (and they keep it up to date with changes made to Source by the Adobe team). That said: where is your HTML and CSS? Without showing how you're effecting this text, we can only guess, and guessing is not very good help.

Comment: Here is it `h1::after {content:"\2192"; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;}`. I was only able to sort this using a custom font.

Comment: don't add it as comment: your post needs to contain some reduced (but [minimal, complete, and verifiable](/help/mcve)) html and css so that people can see what *exactly* you're doing. Otherwise your'e asking them to guess your problem =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

#### Update 21-04-2017

---

Because its a bit overkill to include a whole library just for one arrow. I update my awnser with a better solution.

Generate the `font-icon` yourself with somekind of `application` like https://icomoon.io/app/#/select/

Search for the disired `font-icon`(s) and download the the generated `font`. Just copy and paste the `font` to your hosting and voila.

If you want to keep a clean structure or a clean `css` file. You can also copy the content of the `style.css` into your desired `css` file.

---

#### Original awnser

---

What about using an font icon? Something like Font Awesome.
If so, you have to do this.

include Font Awesome in your header.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Than make the CSS for the ::after element like this.

```
.class:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}

.class:hover:after {
    content: "\f178";
}
```

For detailed info using Font Awesome visit: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

https://jsfiddle.net/bgamsayq/

Comment: I thought about using font awesome but the problem is I'm already embedding font from google and for just one icon adding a new font would be a bit 'demanding' site performance wise.

Comment: Thats true. For that there is a more simpler solution. Create your own font icon and put it inside your style.css. To make things easy there is an awesome website for this: https://icomoon.io/app/#/select Just search for an arrow image and generate the font icon. After you downloaded you icon you can just copy the content of the icomoon style.css into your own style.css.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. That's what I eventually did to make sure that the arrow appears the same in all browsers.